# Merging Two KML Files to Display Them with Different Marker Icons on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

Let's say that I have two spreadsheets with addresses. I uploaded these spreadsheets into Google Fusion Tables, geocoded the addresses, and exported the results as KML files. Now, I want to take these two KML files and merge them, while maintaining the location data and using it to map the points with Google Maps.

Well, I found a way to easily merge the KML files: import both of them into a "My Maps" map with Google Maps! However, my problem is this: when I do that, all of the locations in my data have the same marker icon on the map. From past experience, I know that these markers can be somehow defined inside the KML files. **Is it possible to combine these two KML files while giving one's points one marker icon and the other's points another marker icon?**

Just in case my question is confusing, what I mean, is giving the first set of points blue markers, for example, and the other set of points red markers, so that they can be overlayed.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any tools for doing this, but if you want get your hands dirty you can edit the kml file and add the `<icon>` and `<iconstyle>` elements.

```
<Style id="globeIcon">
  <IconStyle>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon19.png</href>
    </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
</Style>
```

**Sources:**

- [KML Elements Supported in Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps.html)
- [KML Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html#placemarks)